# Unable to use Lighthouse Typescript Definitions

Tags: typescript, lighthouse

Currently trying to use the available Lighthouse Typescript definitions in the npm package, however no matter what I try, the definitions are never available to me within Visual Studio Code.

I've installed only the following packages

- lighthouse
- devtools-protocol
- typescript

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "rootDir": "src",
    "noImplicitAny": false    
  },
  "include": ["./node_modules/lighthouse/types/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

src/app.ts

```
interface Foobar {
    test: <cursor is here>
}
```

When I type `Base`, nothing autocompletes, but I would expect the `BaseArtifacts` definition to be available, which is defined within `./node_modules/lighthouse/types/artifacts.d.ts`

Answer (score 0):

I just realised my mistake.  I'm using both `rootDir` and `include` which cancelled the `include`.

When I change my tsconfig to:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "ES2017",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "strict": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "outDir": "./build",
    "noImplicitAny": false    
  },
  "include": ["./src/**/*", "./node_modules/lighthouse/types/**/*.d.ts"]
}
```

It works as expected